# How to make SESSION cookies last for a year?

Tags: php, session

How do you make a SESSION cookie last for longer?

I'm using this code in the file that logs in my users:

```
<?
session_regenerate_id();
session_set_cookie_params(3600*24*365);
session_start();
$_SESSION['u']['id'] = xxxx;
?>
```

And on the rest of the site I use only `session_start();` to start the session.

The cookie PHPSESSID on the client is set to expire in 365 days but if I don't use the site for a day and come back I'm logged off. Do I have to do something else to make the cookie last longer?

Comment: here is also php session.gc_maxlifetime in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal cookies, you can do this manually while setting the cookie:

```
setcookie($foo, $bar, time()+(3600*24*365));
```

However, session cookies are AUTOMAGICALLY deleted after your browser is closed (unless you are using a browser that specifically saves your sessions across runs). To be honest, if you want sessions to last longer than, well, a session, you should serialize said session with some kind of data persistence, like MySQL.

Comment: two days ago I was told SESSION cookies were more secure and changed everything to SESSION. I'm going to have to change all back again. How would it go? I login and create a row in a table with the session saving a cookie to the client for reference, what then? Do I have to check against the table on every page load to get the user id?

Comment: Session cookies are only as secure as your connection. They aren't inherently anymore secure or less secure than regular HTTP cookies. PHP sessions use HTTP cookies, actually. If you fire up Wireshark, you can actually see the cookies (both session and "regular" HTTP) being passed in the headers. I can tell you from experience that while you may think doing a bunch of processes on every page load is a lot of work, remember that computers are really, really, really fast. So yes, you want to do user checking/logging on every page load.